# Powershell call command line application and pass variables when prompted

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a command line application I would like to call from inside a Powershell script.  The purpose of doing so is so I can pass it values calculated by the script.  Unfortunately the application does not accept command line parameters, but interactively prompts the user for them.

If I do a Write-Host after calling the command line application then the application must complete before the writes are done.  If I pipe the values using Write-Host into the application call, the application behaves as though nothing but return was entered for each of the prompts.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd give this a try:
http://wasp.codeplex.com/